# Is it a good idea to cold-email someone in a museum to ask for PhD funding opportunity?

Tags: phd, funding, united-kingdom

I am an international (non-EU) student and have been offered admission to an art history PhD program in an UK university. However, the offer does not come with funding, and I do not have the financial means to fund it myself. My supervisor advises that I speak to government bodies in my home country to ask for funding, starting with the art museums. This is because my research area is related to the museum’s collection and my research can make an impact on the interpretation of some of these artworks. Additionally, I can work for the museum after I graduate and return to my home country so as to ‘give back’ to the museum for funding my PhD.

I did what my supervisor suggests, and looked for funding opportunities given by the museums. The problem is, there is no mention of any funding opportunity in these museum’s websites. After some digging, I manage to find one person who is now doing her PhD while she is a curator of a particular museum, but I am not sure if the museum funds her PhD or she holds a scholarship from the university. The financial statement of the museum also does not mention anything about scholarship or funding PhD studies.

In my current situation, I am willing to give anything a try. I am thinking of cold-emailing someone from the museum to ask about funding opportunities. Perhaps I can start with the curator who is now doing her PhD, if I am able to find her email online. My questions are, is this an unusual thing to do? Have anyone of you done or receive such cold-email before? What would you advice?

Comment: It sounds like you have no alternative?

Comment: It might not be a good opportunity, but no harm in trying. But expect a 'no' - museums generally are not funding agencies.